# Close cross on Bootstrap modalbox is not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Bootstrap 3. I have a modalbox, where I inserted a cross in the upper right corner with the following Bootstrap code:

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

I actually thought that the bootstrap `class="close"` would close the modal. But It seems that I need something more to make that work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                  <form action="https://zalis.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3be651219436ee0f217f040a5&amp;id=d07c036d2e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                                      <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                       <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                                       <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                     </div> 
                                      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3be651219436ee0f217f040a5_d07c036d2e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                      <div class="clear">
                                          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
 let $input = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe')
  $input.addEventListener('click', function (){
    this.value= "close";
    this.setAttribute('data-dismiss','modal');
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute added to the button in order to close the modal.

```
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                                  <form action="https://zalis.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3be651219436ee0f217f040a5&amp;id=d07c036d2e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                                      <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                       <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                                       <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                     </div> 
                                      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3be651219436ee0f217f040a5_d07c036d2e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                      <div class="clear">
                                          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
 let $input = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe')
  $input.addEventListener('click', function (){
    this.value= "close";
    this.setAttribute('data-dismiss','modal');
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like it is  this style rule - :"#mc_embed_signup form {
    position: relative;
} - if you remove the position relative from that - it seems to work

Comment: Yes I can see that, thank you. But what does that affect if I remove that? I guess there is a reason why it is there?

Comment: usually - a position relative on a parent element is to allow a position: absolute on a child element. Check to see if there is anything like that - but it should be fine to remove - or actually better yet - move the button into a modal-header (which is the common location for it.

Comment: Good good point. Thank you a lot for that. Working perfectly now, when I set it in a header.

Comment: Glad to help - happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-dismiss="modal"` in the close element as an attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                  <form action="https://zalis.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3be651219436ee0f217f040a5&amp;id=d07c036d2e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                                      <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                       <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                                       <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                     </div> 
                                      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3be651219436ee0f217f040a5_d07c036d2e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                      <div class="clear">
                                          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
 let $input = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe')
  $input.addEventListener('click', function (){
    this.value= "close";
    this.setAttribute('data-dismiss','modal');
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-dismiss="modal"` to `close` `button`

[bootstarp-4 modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="mk row">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 margin_bottom">
            <div class="hover11 column">
                <figure>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nyhedsbrev-tilmelding">
                      <img src="https://dohanews.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/headline.png" alt="Sign up for our newsletter" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="nyhedsbrev-tilmelding" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                  <form action="https://zalis.us17.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3be651219436ee0f217f040a5&amp;id=d07c036d2e" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
                                      <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="mc-field-group">
                                       <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                                       <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
                                      </div>
                                      <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                                     </div> 
                                      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3be651219436ee0f217f040a5_d07c036d2e" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                      <div class="clear">
                                          <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
 let $input = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe')
  $input.addEventListener('click', function (){
    this.value= "close";
    this.setAttribute('data-dismiss','modal');
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```